# Could keystroke timing improve security on a password?

Tags: passwords, biometrics

When I was young, and had just started out in my software-development career 20 years ago, I wrote a little bit of code on my Amiga that took a password, but also recorded (within some threshold), the speed at which each letter of a password was typed.

This meant that, not only did the user have to type in the right password, they also had to time the key-presses.  To test it, I'd have a rhythm in my head and could consistently re-type the password every time.  However if I just typed it out regularly, or slowly, it was not accepted.

I am no security expert (my programming lies in less-difficult areas, thankfully), but I just suddenly thought about that program I wrote when I was young and whether it was a viable addition to security these days, or whether it's not even worth thinking about.

*Tap* - *Taptaptap* - *TapTap* -- *Tap*.

Comment: Potential concern: accessibility.

Comment: coursera.com, a site with free/paid college-level courses, does exactly this before each exam to ensure the correct person is taking the exam.  Passwords can be shared, key-timings cannot _(not easily, anyways)_

Comment: Good for musicians and keeping millitary grade secrets safe, bad for everyday use.

Comment: It would for sure increase my frustration since I often type passwords with one hand only, and also on logon failure I go slow and make extra sure I didn't mess up. Also qV519[YW;BAZE*qvjj11 doesn't lend itself to a rythm easily ;) Oh and password managers of course.

Comment: I actually implemented such a system using machine learning, but I found that it is way too unreliable for short inputs like passwords. However, it can be fairly accurate (up to 95% detection rate) when given more input (e.g. a longer facebook post). So it can be used to enhance security *after* a login, e.g. to check if somebody unauthorized just started using the computer. Then you can ask for the password again, just to be sure.

Comment: KeePass, you guys surf this site from time-to-time? I hope you're ready to implement a keystroke algorithm to mimic my natural typing. Once KeyPass does implement this feature (highly likely), how the heck am I supposed to type out `0'=)4S-,5nB?#M76It"1"}?#C` with any sort of consistency for KeePass to mimic?

Comment: Problems: 1) the user must know this in advance 2) typing speed **does** change with time: if you have a random password the first times you are going to type it quite slowly but after a while it goes to muscle-memory and can type it quite fast. 3) What if I broke a finger/arm and for some days/weeks cannot achieve the same timing?  4) All KeePass users  (or other password manager tools) would look the same... probably not a problem since in this case passwords are likely to be strong enough by themselves.  5) Shouldersurfing may become easier.

Comment: What happens when I only have one hand to type with, or I'm really sick / tired? I can't get in? Cool!

Comment: Works great until I decide that I would like to log in from my mobile device and I'm not using an actual keyboard at all...

Comment: @BlueRaja So if I hurt my hand while playing handball the day before an exam, I'll be flagged as a cheater or not capable of logging in? This sounds like a horrible idea that's trivial to circumvent by people who actually want to cheat (hell many keyboards offer such functionality out of the box; not that writing code that does the same thing would take more than half an hour).

Comment: @MathieuK. That's a problem with passwords as it is. I know some blind users who use screenreader software to read out what's on the screen and/or what they are typing, and passwords are read out as "asterisk asterisk asterisk asterisk...". They manage to type the passwords in, but it's time-consuming if the password is complicated or if they are not familiar with where the keys are.

Comment: The PC keyboard, the notebook keyboard and the smartphone keyboard would definitely create different passwords in my case.

Comment: Not to mention that you need to implement this client side which is _impossible_ to make secure. If you're using this as your FDE password, I can simply replace your boot loader (what you're presented with at boot if you have FDE is basically a brute force prompt anyway) and if you're on a website it's even easier.

Comment: Since I change my passwords every once in a while (everyone should change his passwords every once in a while), my typing speed varies depending on the age of the password. Faster and faster, up till I get myself a new password again. Keyrate works for average pieces of texts, but not for things you've memorized like passwords.

Comment: If used as a general heuristic, this would preclude me of my most effective over the shoulder password security technique: As I am entering it, I will randomly switch back and forth between qwerty and Dvorak layouts so that my keystrokes used have a high variability to them.  The cadence of keystrokes has a high dependency upon the relative positions of the keys because the fingers used for each key and the tendons activated for each key transition will differ between layouts.

Comment: The only manner in which this would be an acceptable practice would be if it were not to be a hard barrier to entry but a trigger to notify the account owner if the keystroke pattern did not meet the threshold of the habituation data. If it were used to trigger an "A suspicious login was detected at {14:56} on {20160503}." email to me, that could be acceptable, especially if the information in the system contained my PII or my financial data.  If I was logging in one-handed while I took a drink or was operating another machine, I would be able to ignore the alert but still gain legit access.

Comment: You could ask for the *secret knock* as a second factor.

Comment: Browser's that save and automatically fill in password fields could also pose trouble.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "[keystroke dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_dynamics)" or "keystroke biometrics" and is an interesting and growing field.

The idea is that an individual types certain keys in a certain way that does not change much over time. If you can map those dynamics, then you could, potentially, do away with passwords altogether and simply get the user to type *anything*.

Comment: I heard that during the Second World War the Allied forces spied on the Germans with a hidden microphone in the German message room. The operators were forbidden to talk but the Allied decoders could actually recognise which operator was typing as well as the majority of their messages by the sound of their typing alone! They gave each operator a nickname as they didn't know their actual identities.

Comment: @CJDennis Sounds logical. Those kind of attacks are even still used nowadays. For example: Time the keystrokes of SSH sessions (just by timing the moments of network traffic, not the actual contents) and compare them with common typing patterns of your victim ... or start analyzing them from scratch.

Comment: @CJDennis They certainly used similar techniques when listening-in on encrypted Morse traffic ([see Keystroke Dynamics on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_dynamics#Origin_of_Keystroke_Dynamics) and [notes on a listening station](http://www.harpenden-history.org.uk/page_id__103.aspx)).

Comment: The only drawback to this system is that I just changed my work password. I'm typing it slowly and deliberately now as I'm learning it. In another week or two, I will have developed new muscle memory and will be able to type it much more quickly. Keystroke dynamics would require that I labor through it for the next 90 days until I change it again, and that would be very, very irritating, as well as making it easier to shoulder surf.

Comment: The correct way to use this, as with any *supplemental* biometric marker, is to record a confidence level that the individual accessing the system is who they represent that they are. If the confidence drops below some threshold, alert them through a preselected communication channel (like email) that there is some concern that someone unauthorized may have accessed their login info (at time x through system y, so they have some way to determine if it may have been them). It would be offputting for most uses, but I'd be OK if (say) my bank did that.

Comment: @CJDennis: You're probably thinking of stories that allied radio intercept collectors could recognize the style of different German radio operators.  Sending Morse Code *is* literally broadcasting your telegraph keystrokes over the radio.  An operator's individual pattern is known as their "hand", and this is what Allied listeners would recognize, to help figure out which transmission was coming from the same place as a previous one.  (Radio messages don't come with source address headers).  (I unfortunately wasn't able to google up anything about "hands"; I remember reading it in a book.)

Comment: @FreeMan There's various ways to create the threshold.  Like OP, I experimented with this years ago, and found that at least for me, the length of the pauses between characters scale proportionately between slowly typing a new password and quickly typing an old password.  So if that's true for you as well, and the implementation accounted for it, you wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you are thinking of an operator's *fist*. As well as deliberately tracking enemy operatives' fists, people will just get to know the fist of those the regularly communicate with (or listen in on) just as they would the voice of someone they often talked to, or handwriting of someone they often corresponded with through cursive. Likewise one can have a good or poor fist, just as one can have good or poor diction or handwriting.

Comment: Yup, thanks.  Someone else already reminded me of the correct term, but moderators appear to have deleted our comments instead of moving them to chat with a link.  So now there are only the incomplete / bogus ones.  /sigh.

Comment: @Samthere I named the field and provided how it could be used to increase the security of the password, which is what was asked. 98 people thought my answer was fine, including Moo-Juice. Everyone has an opinion, though.

Comment: @CJDenis - IIRC In Philip Kahn's Codebreakers, One Day of Magic chapter, there's a mention that japanese fleet sailing for attack on Pearl Harbor left its usual radio operators in home waters to pretend that the fleet was still there.

Comment: @Izkata I doubt it holds true if you switch to a keyboard with a different layout (e.g. qwerty/qwertz). I had to suffer this just yesterday and I suspect it totally broke any usual typing dynamics

Answer (score 87):

I think it would be very, very annoying to legitimate users of your application or website. Things like a broken finger, or just holding a sandwich in one hand, would make your login unusable. Additionally, you should encourage the use of password managers, which will either send keystrokes extremely quickly, or will not send keystrokes at all. Your scheme would probably prevent even the best password managers from working.

Comment: And more attacks are probably automated rather than manual, as such the entry is more likely to be similar to a password manager entering the password...

Comment: A password manager could always generate a random keystroke input pattern though, but that doesn't solve the issue of sandwich holders.

Comment: On top of that there is also the issue of different input devices. I bet most people type in very different speeds on their laptop, mobile phone, tablet or Xbox.

Comment: @dirkk - they do.. everyone uses a wide variety of devices, and while this subject is interesting it's ultimately flawed due to the fact people will use different input devices for passwords. Kinda neat idea though, perhaps as a 2nd factor or something..

Comment: @dirkk And then you have the people that switch to alternate layouts like Dvorak that will either get the correct password OR the correct timing but not both when using a different machine with standard layout.

Comment: Or even when it's a standard keyboard but not your own your timing can be impacted.  I'm a 80-wpm typist on a perfect setup.  I'm not nearly that good on my laptop, although I'm better if I plug an external keyboard in that's like my main system--but even then the less than ideal positioning of that keyboard will impact my typing.

Comment: A "sandwich", riiiiight.

Comment: It COULD be used to filter out brute-force attempts. I.e. if the keys are pressed inhumanly fast. Right?

Comment: Some non-human inputs are valid though and you SHOULD NOT filter them out. See my point about password managers.

Answer (score 39):

There's some good, some bad, and some REALLY ugly in here.

**The Good**
It increases a passwords entropy and makes it harder to brute force

**The Bad**
It is based on something that can be audibly recorded and timed and needs fault tolerances meaning something only has to be close enough to render this moot

**The REALLY ugly**
People change over time. For a multitude of reasons(injury, age, forgetting how the pattern goes) they may no longer be able to enter it at that same exact speed and frequency or within tolerances anymore and then it actually harms a users ability to use the service

So while a cool idea and an interesting field, it's really nothing more than hard for human to maintain entropy on the password. Worse yet it's easy to recreate the pattern with machines. It will make it harder to hack without prior knowledge of the person or pattern, but it could also worsen a user's experience with your service over time and make it easier to gather local information about the password entropy.

Comment: but these are all similar pros/cons for any biometric, correct?

Comment: Close. The problem is this isn't just bio-metrics, but also audio-metrics(sound patterns). Bio metrics are better there because you have to see them to record them. This just needs to be nearby for the timing pattern.

Comment: It does bring some really cool entropy to the password though, but that's easy to do without adding an extra system int the first place by just increasing the length or character set.

Comment: "Easy to intercept/replicate" and "easy to forget" is pretty much two of the worst features for a password.

Comment: To add to REALLY UGLY: I often type my password slowly when it does not log in and I'm sure that I'm using the correct one, which leads me to think that I'm miss-pressing a key.

Comment: You can also leave a mobile device beside the keyboard to capture the pattern. https://www.ted.com/talks/avi_rubin_all_your_devices_can_be_hacked?language=en, about 12:55.

Answer (score 18):

> whether it was a viable addition to security these days

The only reason I don't think it would be viable is people log in from so many different devices these days.  I can promise you there is no correlation to the rhythm I type my password with on my main work desktop and the Swype keyboard on my tablet.

Comment: Even laptop vs. desktop, or you use different keyboard layout (work in English, personal system in another language, or you like dvorak).

Comment: standing in the bus with your phone vs sitting at your desk in front of the pc

Comment: For that matter, I have different mouse/keyboard combinations for the same device (laptop).  When I'm traveling, I use a mini-keyboard, or even the one that's molded into the laptop, when I'm at my desk at work, I have a different keyboard/mouse set than I do at home, etc.  The timing on my keystrokes varies wildly according to that, in addition to time of day (caffeine/tired) and gawd only knows what else.  Keystroke dynamics are just a fundamentally poor choice for a security feature.

Answer (score 13):

**Yes, it's more secure. It would make a 8 character timed password as strong as a ~9.5 characters long non-timed password.**

**This would be a form of [keystroke dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_dynamics)**. It's been an area in active research for a while - although software running on an Amiga probably predates most of it!

[There's a python package for that](https://github.com/goncalopp/keystroke_dynamics), in case you want to experiment in a more modern language.

**Some modern services actually use this technique** - like Coursera, [who uses it to make sure the person who is answering a test is the actual user](http://www.biometricupdate.com/201301/coursera-looks-to-verify-online-student-identity-with-photo-keystroke-dynamics).

---

Let's explore a bit of theory in order to answer your question. The [usual options for human authentication](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs513/2005fa/nnlauthpeople.html) are:

- Something you know (password, pin-code)
- Something you have (cell phone, hardware token, smart card)
- Something you are (fingerprint, iris, [gait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gait_%28human%29)). Usually [biometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biometrics).

Keystroke dynamics belong in the third category. Usually, good authentication systems rely on having more than one of these. When using two different systems, this is commonly known as [two-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication).

---

**Usually, biometrics come with a couple of caveats**:

- They may change over time. Your typing pattern will change with the time of day, your chair and desk height, the keyboard you're using, and many other factors
- They may be irretrievably lost. If you manage to lose a finger, you won't ever be able to authenticate.

Your design, however, is not employing a traditional biometric. You are asking the user to *remember* a typing pattern. This would fall in the first category (*something you know*), so, effectively, you can measure the amount of security it adds using [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29).

Assuming your system has two possible key press durations (which your example seems to imply), this adds one bit of entropy per character - thus it would make a 8 character timed password around as strong as a ~9.5 characters long non-timed password.

---

Of course, the design has flaws as well, when compared to biometric keystroke dynamics:

- the fact that the pattern is very distinctive will make it more susceptible to an attacker with a audio recorder
- Since the pattern is *known* by the user, they can be coerced into revealing it. Traditional keystroke dynamics can be used as [implicit authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_authentication).

Comment: "this adds one bit of entropy per character - thus it would make a 8 character timed password around as strong as a ~9.5 characters long non-timed password." This sounds wrong. One additional bit per character should give you 8 extra bits. Assuming you normally have 1.1 bits/character, you'd have ~ 8.8 + 8 = 16.8, equivalent to 15.2 characters, not 9.5. Furthermore I'd say that what counts is not the number of letters, but rather the number of intervals between letters, so it would be 7, not 8, but this is less important.

Comment: @FabioTurati My bad for not stating my assumptions :) **I assumed a random password with a character set of length 36**, [which gives you 5.17 bits per character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Random_passwords). `(5.17 * 8 + 8) / 5.17 ~= 9.5`. I'm not sure where you're getting the 1.1 bits/character from, it sounds very low - perhaps for a non-random numeric pin?

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking of typical English words, and based on [this](http://what-if.xkcd.com/34/) ("Shannon determined that the information content of typical written English was around 1.0 to 1.2 bits per letter") I had the value of 1.1 bits/character. But now I see what you mean. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

It's a neat idea, and the (theoretical) net effect would be an increase in password entropy. For example, suppose your threshold is 1/4 second and the maximum pause is 1 second. At some point the pauses would be converted into bits, and this would effectively increase the password character set by 4X; e.g. an 80 character set would become a 320 character set. A 10 digit password with 80 possible characters would become 1 million times more difficult to brute force by implementing your idea. Another way to say that is your 10 character password would become more like 13 or 14 characters.

Practically speaking, the main benefit I see would be that it is probably easier for humans to remember the rhythm to a song combined with 10 characters than it is to remember 14 characters. But the best passwords are those that humans can't remember anyway, so it would probably be a lot simpler (for all parties involved) to just add a few more characters to your password to achieve the same increase in entropy.

Furthermore, (as *elixenide* points out in the comment), forcing a user to type in a password rather than pasting it would actually decrease entropy overall, because it discourages complex passwords that would normally be pasted in from a password manager instead of physically typed.

Comment: It would likely *decrease* entropy by making it difficult or impossible to use a password manager. A user who has to be able to remember a password and type it consistently will not use a long or complex password. The entropy boost from recording the keyboard timing of a 10-digit password is miniscule compared to the entropy *loss* from encouraging shorter passwords versus the very long, very complex passwords that password managers handle with no problem.

Comment: @elixenide great point. I updated the answer to reflect this. (Better late than never.)

Answer (score 7):

Since this basically precludes use of a password manager, which is baseline best-practices for password security, it does not improve but harms password security.

Comment: It should work with a lightning-speed typing password manager, but that would become the *only* way to login

Comment: What if you use it for the password **of** the password manager? ;)

Comment: Sounds like a great way to get locked out of everything.

Comment: @R.. It's fun when that happens; you either get to crack the encryption of your password manager, or you have to remember your passwords. Fun fun fun.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: With proper use of a password manager your passwords are not rememberable because you never knew/saw them to begin with. They're all long random strings.

Comment: @R.. And with a proper password manager, you can't crack the encryption. Fun fun fun.

Answer (score 5):

I've done a little work in this, and some related areas, and my response to the question depends on how much time you've got:

Short answer: Yes, with a but.

Simply put, as you've discovered previously, there are similarities in observed keystroke (or other behavioral biometric patterns). These can, theoretically, be used for additional security, but the false-positive and false-negative rates are still comparatively high, so usability is questionable, and there aren't any pre-built libraries that I would recommend as reliable.

Longer Answer: No, with a however.

The problem with behavioral biometrics in the context of security is that it doesn't fit with our current models. If you're given a password, it's either right, or it's wrong. If something's measuring your iris, it's a match or it isn't. There's no leeway or wiggle room, one or the other, binary authentication.

Behaviorals don't do this. Behaviors change depending on the time of day, the time of month, the weather outside. You can say "this *looks* like this person", but there's no cut and dry "yes/no" response, which makes them bad at traditional authentication, particularly with short sample sizes like passwords.

On the other hand, there are a *lot* of behavioral analytics that can be measured (network usage, keystroke, mouse usage, movement, and a wealth of others). These *can* be combined to give a sustained confidence indication over a prolonged period. So, for example, you could log onto your machine, and it wouldn't let you access your bank because it's not verified you yet. Do a few other things you need to, work for a while, and the algorithms return a good confidence value, and access is granted to privileged systems.

Essentially, the binary authentication routes currently in place are not well suited to behavioral biometrics, but there's a lot of promise for trust-based authentication further down the line.

Answer (score 4):

Another reason for no: Assume your user mistypes their password occasionally. *You* may type it perfectly, but the rest of us have fat fingers sometimes.  They will probably type it more slowly on the second attempt and screw up your metrics.  This is particularly true if there's any detectable timeout/delay (rate-limiting or just a slow login server) as they wouldn't want to wait for another delay having already been annoyed by the first

Answer (score 1):

Let's call this *timed password entry*.

Essentially, what you are doing is this:

- Trying to increase the password entropy.

This has some cons, such as the fact that people change, and it might bite you back after some years.

The question is: is this method of increasing password entropy worth it? To answer this correctly, you need to first *measure* total entropy gained by requiring a timed password entry.

I would argue that you won't gain much entropy, because most people would generally use keyboards about similarly. So when you know that most people generally use keyboards about similarly, you will know that there isn't much entropy (or information) in knowing the timed typing.

Therefore I suggest that:

- Timed password entries are not worth the risks.
- If you need more entropy, just use higher quality passwords (longer with more random letters).

Comment: "most people would generally use keyboards about similarly" Do you have a reference for this? I would expect that people use keyboards in ways that are notably different.

Comment: No. It's just my observation. What I observed is that there is a few classes of keyboard usage methods. I'd imagine at most 5 classes, and it's highly likely to be distributed in a way that is not uniform. E.g. some classes have a huge user base, while other shave little. Therefore, if you measure entropy gained by those 5 non-uniformly distributed classes, it should be less entropy than just adding 2.3 bits.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very cool idea, but if it wasn't implemented correctly as everyone else has said it wouldn't work because people change and the fault tolerance would have to be implemented correctly.

My idea for a good way for this to be implemented would be to see if the user inputs their password in the certain time pattern and if it isn't and the password is correct then you could use this information to make the request seem a bit suspicious and have other things like maybe asking the user to get a text to their phone to make sure it is really them.

*The Pros:* the user enters their password normally, if it is out of time then you can go to secondary measures of authentication. This would only bother the user if they type it in abnormally or if their is someone trying to get into their account.

*The Cons:* their could be false positives that could annoy the user trying to login, and the timings could be seen and/or recorded by someone looking over your shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes it can work, if handled properly

The benefits are clear: it is harder for someone else to log in with your password. Guessing becomes harder, and even if someone has (part of) your password, he's not done yet.

So, I will adress the concerns:

### Yes you can still log in with a broken finger

Sure, the password can get 'lost' when you break your finger, but this can be remedied by making a (stronger) master password available. If you ever have circumstances that do not enable you to keep your rythem, you can always use the master password to get in. (And change the rythem if needed).

### Yes you can still use multiple devices

Obviously different kinds of devices will have different rythems, but if you use them frequently, the rythem per device should be stable enough. As such, you can allow users to have multiple valid rythems.

### Yes you can still use password managers

Obviously password managers could be made to submit the rythem as well as the keystrokes. Though this may be challenging, it could be very easy to just use the aforemetioned master password when logging in with the password manager.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have it brutally block/allow the user you could have it " learn " the user's method over a period of 10-20 logins and take the median with a slight margin of timing.

Regular login:
- Password + two factor login by app / sms / email link

After a while you'll know his pattern, and can give the user the option to enable the added security, and then lower the amount of times he needs to log in with the two factor login. (presuming the same IP was used)

When the added security is active, you could then allow the user to login with just the password as long as the IP source is the same.
Giving him an easier / faster login method.
And when you detect the user is varying his login tap tap tap speed a lot from earlier registrations, you could ask for the two factor login again and update the list. (always take the median over 5 login attempts, eliminating the extremes)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this would have the most potential for situations where a password is used often and the input doesn't allow a large variety of characters. An obvious example would be something like a door entry code. This also has the advantage that even if somebody is able to see the code itself over your shoulder they still have to get the rhythm right. This also allows you to get more entropy out of a very basic input device.

You could even imagine a situation where there is just one button and they rhythm is the only input, after all this is a digital version of the 'secret knock'.

If nothing else this may have some novelty value for low level security applications and may even have more serious niche for say professional musicians who would be expected to have a very accurate sense of timing.